# can i detect obstacles with hector_costmap with only laser scanner?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, sicklms, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I (only) have laser scanner LMS100 and i can create maps from hector_slam without odometry data...but i need to see obstacles / objects in the map.

So i think i should use a costmap like hector_costmap (or costmap_2d which is in another package)...but i don't now if it is usable with just laser data (without odometry data).

update: i tried and managed gmapping with laser scan matcher, so i now i think i can use costmap_2d in navigation stack with help of those...

by the way still dont know, can i use hector_costmap without odometry data?

Başak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235986/can-i-detect-obstacles-with-hector_costmap-with-only-laser-scanner?/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjbecomespheh](https://answers.ros.org/users/55607/jjbecomespheh/) on 2020-07-16**:
Hi Basak, may I ask if you managed to hector_costmap for detecting obstacles using just laser data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

you could try using this package to estimate odometry data from laserscans.
http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0